# React JS making API calls in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, dom, axios

I have created and processed React app in development mode allows for successful communication with my API by Proxying API Requests from package.json.

But when I create a production build for my React app and process it using serve -s build communication with my API is unsuccessful and fails while Proxying API Requests from package.json.

I have used AXIOS to make API calls

My question is, why isn't the API loading in production /build?

If proxying doesn't work in production build how should I make API calls

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide more details and some code. adding your `axios` config and related `package.json` can help the community to help you with your problem.